# What might have caused by display to become less colorful and how might I restore it?

Tags: osx-lion, colors, external-display, display-settings

I have an HP LP3065 display and a few days ago upon returning to the computer (others in the family probably had used is between my sessions) I noticed that all the colors seemed a bit subdued.  This is not the case for the MacBook Air's built in screen.  I am running OS X Lion.  It is almost as if there was a slider between black and white and color and someone moved it closer to black and white.  Could this be due to a software setting on my Mac?  Or perhaps it is a hardware setting on the display?  There are plus and minus buttons on the display but pressing them seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see if the Color Profile settings have changed?  Go to System Preferences, Displays, Color.  Try choosing a different profile, if one isn't available for your specific monitor.

Comment: I had checked, nothing appeared changed to me.